# Filter prompt for dojo data grid is improperly formatted

Tags: xpages, dojox.grid.datagrid

I'm working in Xpages and attempting to create my first dojo data grid.  I have a grid of data.  However, I think I'm missing a css class somewhere because the column sort options don't look correct and the filter prompt window is way too small, resulting in everything being bunched up and unreadable / unusable.  What am I missing?

[image: Here is what I get...]

Here is the source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" dojoParseOnLoad="true"
    dojoTheme="true">

    <xp:this.resources>
        <xp:dojoModule name="dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid"></xp:dojoModule>
        <xp:dojoModule name="dojox.grid.enhanced.plugins.DnD"></xp:dojoModule>
        <xp:dojoModule
            name="dojox.grid.enhanced.plugins.NestedSorting">
        </xp:dojoModule>
        <xp:dojoModule
            name="dojox.grid.enhanced.plugins.IndirectSelection">
        </xp:dojoModule>
        <xp:dojoModule name="dojox.grid.enhanced.plugins.Filter"></xp:dojoModule>
        <xp:dojoModule name="dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore"></xp:dojoModule>

        <xp:styleSheet
            href="/.ibmxspres/dojoroot/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css">
        </xp:styleSheet>
        <xp:styleSheet
            href="/.ibmxspres/dojoroot/dojox/grid/resources/Grid.css">
        </xp:styleSheet>
        <xp:styleSheet
            href="/.ibmxspres/dojoroot/dojox/grid/resources/tundraGrid.css">
        </xp:styleSheet>
        <xp:styleSheet
            href="/.ibmxspres/dojoroot/dojox/grid/enhanced/esources/EnhancedGrid.css">
        </xp:styleSheet>
        <xp:styleSheet
            href="/.ibmxspres/dojoroot/dojox/grid/enhanced/esources/tundraEnhancedGrid.css">
        </xp:styleSheet>
    </xp:this.resources>

    <xp:br></xp:br>


    <xp:div id="gridDiv"></xp:div>

    <xp:eventHandler event="onClientLoad" submit="false">
    <xp:this.script>
        <xp:executeClientScript>
            <xp:this.script><![CDATA[dojo.addOnLoad(function(){

   //setup the grid layout, format = {'name': 'columntitle', 'field': 'fieldname'}

    var layout = [{
    defaultCell: {editable: false, type: dojox.grid.cells._Widget},
    rows:[
       {'field': "qtno", 'name': "Quote No.", 'width': '40px'},
       {'field': "cusno", 'name': "Cust #", 'width': '60px'},
       {'field': "cusnm", 'name': "Customer", 'width': '150px'},
       {'field': "qtamt", 'name': "Quote Amt", 'width': '40px', 'datatype':'number'},  
       ]    
    }]

    //setup data store
    var data = {
      identifier: 'id',
      items: []
    };

    //setup data array of strings, format = {fieldname: "strvalue", fieldname: numvalue} 
    var data_list = [
      { qtno: "Q01234", cusno: "4419", cusnm: "ABC Corporation", qtamt: 29.91},
      { qtno: "Q42198", cusno: "3308", cusnm: "Acme Company", qtamt: 9.33},
      { qtno: "Q11095", cusno: "7041", cusnm: "XYZ Industries", qtamt: 19.34}
    ];

    //default the rows
    var rows = data_list.length;

    //populate the store with the data array of strings
    for(var i=0, l=data_list.length; i<rows; i++){
      data.items.push(dojo.mixin({ id: i+1 }, data_list[i%l]));
    }
    var store = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({data: data});

    //define the grid
    var grid = new dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid({
        id: 'grid',
        query: {}, 
        store: store,
        structure: layout,
        rowSelector: '20px',  
        autoHeight: 125,
        plugins:{nestedSorting:true, dnd:true, filter:true}
    }, '#{id:gridDiv}');

    //create it
    grid.startup();

})


]]></xp:this.script>
        </xp:executeClientScript>
    </xp:this.script></xp:eventHandler></xp:view>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a bug in your own code :-) Change your reference to the EnhancedGrid CSS files from /esources to /resources.

```
<xp:styleSheet>
    href="/.ibmxspres/dojoroot/dojox/grid/enhanced/resources/EnhancedGrid.css">
</xp:styleSheet>
<xp:styleSheet
    href="/.ibmxspres/dojoroot/dojox/grid/enhanced/resources/tundraEnhancedGrid.css">
</xp:styleSheet>
```

Comment: Oh my gosh, unbelievable... ugh... THANK YOU!